# UIView.transition with delay

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewanimation

I have simultaneous animations going on, and I would like to transition the VC in the middle (it will fade so it will see some of the other animations). However, I can't find documentation how to delay a transition similar to UIView.animateWithDuration.

I want to achieve this...

```
UIView.transition(withDuration: 0.5, delay: 0.1, options: .transitionCrossDissolve, animations: {})
```

I can manually add a delay like so.. but was wondering if there's a more elegant way.

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {}
```

Comment: how about :   UIView.animateWithDuration  0.1, animations {UIView.transition(withDuration: 0.5){. } }

Comment: @E.Coms Did you just copy someone else's answer?

Comment: That's different. He puts in completion, I put in animation block.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no. Using a bunch of UIView transitions/animations can get a little hairy.

In the past, I've resorted to setting up an NSTimer that fires 1/30 seconds and I ended up managing all the start times on my own.

What you can do is series out the animations using the closure.

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: { 
}, completion: {Do UIView transition here})
```

Comment: More accurately:-    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, animations: { 
}, completion: { (finished: Bool) in    // transition here   })

Answer (score 0):

It seems no way except surrounding with Timer:

```
Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 5, repeats: true, block: { _ in
    UIView.transition(with: self.myImageView, duration: 0.75,
                      options: [.transitionCrossDissolve],
                      animations: {
        self.myImageView.image = newImage
    })
})
```